# Encode euro, yen and pound symbols in ios

Tags: ios6, nsstring, url-encoding

I am trying to encode  using

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return ( NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]%£",
                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

I am successfully encoding these characters. i would like to encode euro, pound, symbols also. Please guide me, thanks in advance.